Refactor Yii monolith to angular micro-frontends (nx-monorepo)
I have a big monolith project written on PHP (Yii) and JavaScript (jQuery).
What strategy can I choose to refactor this monolith into angular micro-frontends (nx-monorepo)?
I also want to use SSR.
Tell me, who had a similar experience?
Where did you start?
What problems awaited you along this path?
I'm currently considering the option partial integration of angular applications in YII via Iframe, but I think this is not the best option.
Perhaps there is some more concise option using feature flags and partially wrapping traffic in an angular application.
